# jQuery not finding elements (or updating class) after AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, bind

I have a lot of working functions using the jQuery.on() event, and they work fine - but only if it is binded to an element (like "a.my-link" or something).

This function hovever, is bind to the **document or body**, and then traverses multiple elements with the same class attribute. I have commented the lines, which do not fire.

- selectable["holder"]: elements with the class "a.fr-drive-selectable"
- if selected it adds the class "fr-drive-selected"
- if more than one were selected (multiple), then it adds the class "fr-drive-selected-b"

I also have a function for selecting multiple elements using only the CTRL key + mouse - it works, because the on() function is binded to the element ...

```js
    /**
     *  Selecting or deselecting all available items (CTRL + ALT + A)
     *
     *  - Selecting: CTRL + ALT + A
     *  - Deselecting: CTRL + ALT + D
     */
    page.$body.on("keydown", function (shortcut) {
        if (shortcut.ctrlKey && shortcut.altKey && shortcut.key === "a") {
            selectable["$holder"].each(function () {
                if (!$(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).hasClass(selectable["multiple"]["class"])) {
                    if (!(items.indexOf(parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'))) > -1)) {
                        addItem(items, $(this)); // WORKS FINE!
                    }

                    addContextMenuOption($(this)); // WORKS FINE!

                    console.log(items); // WORKS FINE!

                    $(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).removeClass(selectable["one"] ["class"]); //NOT WORKING AFTER AJAX
                    $(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).addClass(selectable["multiple"]["class"]); //NOT WORKING AFTER AJAX
                }
            });
        } else if (shortcut.ctrlKey && shortcut.altKey && shortcut.key === "d") {
            selectable["$holder"].each(function () {
                if ($(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).hasClass(selectable["multiple"]["class"]) || $(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).hasClass(selectable["one"]["class"])) {
                    $(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).removeClass(selectable["multiple"]["class"]); //NOT WORKING AFTER AJAX
                    $(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).removeClass(selectable["one"]["class"]); //NOT WORKING AFTER AJAX

                    resetContextMenuOptions(); // WORKS FINE!

                    items = []; // WORKS FINE!

                    console.log("Removed ALL"); // WORKS FINE!
                }
            });
        }

        updateItemCounter(items); // WORKS FINE!
    });
```

The function works if no dynamic data is appended - after that, it only removes items, but not the classes (add() or remove()). I have used the console to print out elements - objects in each() after AJAX do not have "up to date" class attributes.

**I know the problem is that** the event is not **bind** to the elements in question, but I need a shortcut for handling the key event on the page, not on the element.

---

Similar function (works great, because it uses the element):

```js
        main_content["$holder"].on('contextmenu', 'a.fr-drive-file-selectable', function (ev) {
            if (!(findItemById(items, $(this).attr("data-id")))) {
                $(this).siblings(selectable["selector"]).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).removeClass(selectable["multiple"]["class"]);
                $(this).siblings(selectable["selector"]).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).removeClass(selectable["one"]["class"]);

                //resetContextMenuOptions();

                items = [];

                console.log("Adding one item (RESET)");
                addItem(items, $(this));

                console.log(items);

                $(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).removeClass(selectable["multiple"]["class"]);
                $(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).addClass(selectable["one"]["class"]);
            }
        });
```

For clarity, check out the console output. The blue line indicates the elements found on "keydown" event before AJAX updated the data. After that, jQuery does not find any element matching: "a.fr-drive-file-selectable - **they are on the page!**

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz6jK.png)

** Additional info (after an answer was provided) **

```js
<div id="main-content" class="fr-content">

    <!-- AJAX CHANGES CONTENTS with the same elements, same class etc. (only the inner HTML of the elements is changed (ex. name, picture etc.)  -->

    <div class="fr-drive-file-selectable"><!-- name, picture --></div>
    <div class="fr-drive-file-selectable"><!-- name, picture --></div>
    <div class="fr-drive-file-selectable"><!-- name, picture --></div>
    <div class="fr-drive-file-selectable"><!-- name, picture --></div>
    <div class="fr-drive-file-selectable"><!-- name, picture --></div>

</div>

<script>
    var selectable = {
        $holder: $("a.fr-drive-file-selectable"),
        "class": ".fr-drive-file-selectable"
    }
</script>
<script>
    ...
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (response["status"]) {
            $(id).html(response["fragment"]); //Loads only div.fr-drive-file-selectable (using foreach in PHP)

            stopPageLoader();

            adjustSidenavHeight();
        } else {
         ///
        }
    });
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: You need to include you AJAX function to check because it seems to be changing the DOM elements.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it does. Appends new data, gives a class (not always) ... but like I wrote, the second function works like a charm, only the function for traversing is not wokring. Is it using the old DOM elements (because no direct (this)) is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here it goes ... found the answer. I DON'T KNOW WHY, if someone could later clarify.

So I simply changed the line `selectable["$holder"]` and declared a local variable within the function (check //DIFF).

**Altered code**

```js
 page.$body.on("keydown", .... {

   let selector = "a.fr-drive-file-selectable";

   $(this).find(selectable["$holder"]) // DIDNT WORK, works before AJAX updates DOM!
   $(this).find(selector) // works ... why?

   //selectable["$holder"].each(function () { CHANGED TO

   $(this).find(selector).each(function () { // NEW CODE

   ...
}
```

**Full code**

```js
    /**
     *  Selecting or deselecting all available items (CTRL + ALT + A)
     *
     *  - Selecting: CTRL + ALT + A
     *  - Deselecting: CTRL + ALT + D
     */
    page.$body.on("keydown", function (shortcut) {
        let selector = "a.fr-drive-file-selectable";

        if (shortcut.ctrlKey && shortcut.altKey && shortcut.key === "a") {
            $(this).find(selector).each(function () {
                if (!$(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).hasClass(selectable["multiple"]["class"])) {
                    if (!(items.indexOf(parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'))) > -1)) {
                        addItem(items, $(this));
                    }

                    addContextMenuOption($(this));

                    console.log(items);

                    $(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).removeClass(selectable["one"]["class"]);
                    $(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).addClass(selectable["multiple"]["class"]);
                }
            });
        } else if (shortcut.ctrlKey && shortcut.altKey && shortcut.key === "d") {
            $(this).find(selector).each(function () {
                if ($(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).hasClass(selectable["multiple"]["class"]) || $(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).hasClass(selectable["one"]["class"])) {
                    $(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).removeClass(selectable["multiple"]["class"]);
                    $(this).children(fdrive["content"]["class"]).removeClass(selectable["one"]["class"]);

                    resetContextMenuOptions();

                    items = [];

                    console.log("Removed ALL");
                }
            });
        }

        updateItemCounter(items);
    });
```

Comment: There is a hack for this also. Using setTimeout() and it works, without declaring the local variable or changing the call. I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have enough rep to add a comment.

Maybe you are trying to reference the elements before they are added to the DOM.

Also for dynamic elements try mentioning the parent element followed by the element you want to access in the selector query as follows.

```
$(".parent .dynamic-child").removeClass();
```

Comment: I answered my question, but I must confess I did not try with the parent ... The problem is, that the class or $holder is saved as an JS object and used all around the page. So adding the parent would not be a good idea.

Comment: try to log the value inside 'selectable["$holder"]' using 'console.log[selectable["$holder"]]'.

Comment: Check the console output - I did that. Using the local variable or "class" it worked.